# Can not remove a tar.gz file with a Cron job

Tags: linux, cron

I have a Cron job as below:

```
#!/bin/sh
mysqldump -u .... -p.... ..... > /part/"abc-backup-$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').sql"
tar -zcf /part/"abc-backup-$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').tar.gz" /part/"abc-backup-$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').sql"    
rm -R /home/backupmysql/"ohay-backup-$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').tar.gz"
```

I don't know why

```
rm -R /home/backupmysql/"ohay-backup-$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').tar.gz"
```

will not work

This is the response from the SSH command when I test Cron.

```
.....tar.gz\r': No such file or directory
```

(this file exist)

What's wrong?

Comment: Does the file exist in that specific folder? Your previous commands are compressing to /part/...

Comment: Also, notice there is a \r at the end of the file name. Try to edit the script, push backspace and delete all the .gz" and then write them again. There should be no \r

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO)! I updated the grammar and formatting of your post. Warnings are easier to read when they are on their own line, and are formatted like code (indented with 4 spaces). Also, make sure that products, languages, and utilities have proper casing. Lastly, beware of words like witch vs. which, and bellow vs. below. Have a good day!

Comment: a `\r` char almost certainly means you edited your script on Windows and then transferred to linux. Use `dos2unix myScript.sh` to remove all `\r` chars from your script file. (Even if you didn't edit on Windows, this should work (maybe make a backup)). Good luck.

Comment: Thank you Shellter, it's work!

Answer (score 0):

a `\r` char almost certainly means you edited your script on Windows and then transferred to linux. Use `dos2unix myScript.sh` to remove all `\r` chars from your script file. (Even if you didn't edit on Windows, this should work (maybe make a backup)). Good luck.
                    – shellter